# How to insert user-defined fields in a Word document?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office, microsoft-word-2010

How do you insert a user-defined field in a `Word` document?

I am using `Word 2010`.

Answer (score 4):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F9</kbd> should do the trick. This shortcut enters in an empty field. You may have to enter <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F9</kbd> to bring it to "field edit" mode, which should show double curly brackets. From there, feel free to use any [field codes](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/word-help/field-codes-in-word-HA102110133.aspx) you need.